# Одушевленные или нет?

Tags: лингвистика

Говорит "три кошки" или "три собаки". Но ведь и "кошка", и "собака" - одушевленные существительные. Почему же тогда не "трое кошек" или "трое собак".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Трое** - собирательное числительное. Собирательные числительные сочетаются: 1) с существительными мужского и общего рода, называющими лиц: *двое друзей*, трое парней; 2) с существительными, имеющими формы только множественного числа: *двое саней, трое ножниц*; 3) с существительными *дети, ребята, люди*, с существительным *лицо* в значении 'человек': *двое детей, трое ребят, трое молодых людей, четверо незнакомых лиц*; 4) с личными местоимениями мы, вы, они: *нас двое, вас трое, их было пятеро*.

В разговорной речи диапазон сочетаемости шире (об этом можно прочитать, например, у РОзенталя).

Предпочтительно употребление собирательных числительных: 1) с субстантивированными прилагательными мужского рода: *двое прохожих, трое больных, четверо конвойных*; 2) с существительными мужского рода, имеющими окончание -а: *двое мужчин, трое юношей*.

Что касается вашего вопроса, то употребление собирательных числительных с существительными "кошка" и "собака" носит явно разговорный характер. А вот с количественными ("*три кошки*" или "*три собаки*") - вполне нейтрально.

Comment: А вот еще интересно, почему язык накладывает именнно такие ограничения? Я иногда говорю, что так язык отражает неверие в женскую дружбу,позволяя называть лиц мужского пола как единое целое и запрещая это для  женского. А Вы как думаете?

Answer (score 2):

Собирательные числительные употребляются также с существительными, обозначающими детенышей животных. И еще.  Собирательные числительные  употребляются , когда нужно обозначить совокупность предметов. Например, двое ребят, пятеро котят, трое друзей. Но это не значит, что нельзя говорить пять котят или три друга. Если во дворе два котенка: один возле первого подъезда, другой возле второго - я скажу именно два, а не двое. А если эти котята играют вместе, то правильнее будет сказать двое котят.